# Palm tree rot , bark missing

Tags: trees, diseases, watering, rot

I have a queen palm with the same issue . Bark missing and tree rot . How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please [edit] to include detailed pictures of the damage, and (presumably) to link to the question that "has the same issue." As it is this is vague and unclear and as such not likely to get a good answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.